# Docker Images : Shared memory is not showing as per expected inspite of using that image in FROM

Tags: docker

I have a docker file `Dockerfile_alpine3.11_python3.7.7`

```
FROM python:3.7.7-alpine3.11

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN adduser -u 1000 -G users -h /home/test -D test

RUN chown 1000:100 /home/test

RUN pip install pipenv

ENV PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT 1

WORKDIR /home/test/app

RUN chown 1000:100 /home/test/app

USER test
```

And i build the image as following:

```
$ docker build -t django:python-3.7.7-alpin3.11 --file Dockerfile_alpine3.11_python3.7.7 .
```

Checking the image

```
$ docker image ls
REPOSITORY                        TAG                      IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
django                            python-3.7.7-alpin3.11   9a329bf96093        6 seconds ago       139MB
python                            3.7.7-alpine3.11         61681f520204        2 days ago          96MB
```

Checking the image size

```
$ docker system df -v
Images space usage:

REPOSITORY                        TAG                      IMAGE ID            CREATED              SIZE                SHARED SIZE         UNIQUE SIZE         CONTAINERS
django                            python-3.7.7-alpin3.11   9a329bf96093        About a minute ago   139.3MB             95.96MB             43.36MB             0
python                            3.7.7-alpine3.11         61681f520204        2 days ago           95.96MB             95.96MB             0B                  0
```

**HERE BOTH SHOW THE SHARED MEMORY OF 95.96MB**

Now i am building another Docker file `Dockerfile_alpine_build_deps_for_alpine3.11_python3.7.7` using the image `django:python-3.7.7-alpin3.11` just build

```
FROM django:python-3.7.7-alpin3.11

USER root

RUN apk update \
  # psycopg2 dependencies
  && apk add --no-cache --virtual build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev \
  && apk add --no-cache postgresql-dev \
  # pyzmq dependencies
  && apk add --no-cache build-base libzmq musl-dev zeromq-dev

USER simha
```

Now i build using

```
$ docker build -t django:python-3.7.7-alpin3.11-with-builddeps --file Dockerfile_alpine_build_deps_for_alpine3.11_python3.7.7 .
```

Now check the image

```
$ docker image ls
REPOSITORY                        TAG                                     IMAGE ID            CREATED              SIZE
django                            python-3.7.7-alpin3.11-with-builddeps   0f6ec117e7d7        About a minute ago   426MB
django                            python-3.7.7-alpin3.11                  9a329bf96093        8 minutes ago        139MB
python                            3.7.7-alpine3.11                        61681f520204        2 days ago           96MB
```

Now check the shared size

```
$ docker system df -v                                                                                                                                               
Images space usage:

REPOSITORY                        TAG                                     IMAGE ID            CREATED              SIZE                SHARED SIZE         UNIQUE SIZE         CONTAINERS
django                            python-3.7.7-alpin3.11-with-builddeps   0f6ec117e7d7        About a minute ago   426.3MB             139.3MB             287MB               0
django                            python-3.7.7-alpin3.11                  9a329bf96093        8 minutes ago        139.3MB             139.3MB             0B                  0
python                            3.7.7-alpine3.11                        61681f520204        2 days ago           95.96MB             95.96MB             0B                  0
```

**It shows the SHARED SIZE as expected**
[image]

But if i change the Dockerfile :  `Dockerfile_alpine_build_deps_for_alpine3.11_python3.7.7` a bit then the shared size changes

```
FROM python:3.7.7-alpine3.11

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

ARG CACHEBUST=1 #### ADDED THIS LINE

RUN adduser -u 1000 -G users -h /home/simha -D simha

RUN chown 1000:100 /home/simha

RUN pip install pipenv

ENV PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT 1

WORKDIR /home/simha/app

RUN chown 1000:100 /home/simha/app

USER simha
```

Build the image:

```
$ docker build -t django:python-3.7.7-alpin3.11 --build-arg CACHEBUST=$(date +%s_%N) --file Dockerfile_alpine3.11_python3.7.7 .
```

Check the image size now

[image]

I see the shared sizes changes.

But Each of the three images are interdependent

Comment: 1st example: You have image  A -> B -> C  It means all layers from B are shared =>139Mb.  2nd example, you have A->B and A->C  (no link between B and C ) only the layers of A are shared => 95Mb

Comment: A->C how are they connected. The link for A->C is through B not direct

Comment: 2nd case: "FROM python:3.7.7-alpine3.11" => A -> C no B in it